# JMeter GUI - Set default settings for exporting results to CSV file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

How to set default settings in JMeter for exporting result to csv file?

It keeps asking in pop up below

[image]

- Since JMeter 3.3

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Update `jmeter.properties` in JMeter's bin folder: uncomment the property

```
#resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=ASK
```

and choose value between 2 options (instead of ASK):

```
# APPEND : Append results to existing file
# DELETE : Delete existing file and start a new file
```

save the fle, and restart JMeter

Comment: **resultcollector.action_if_file_exists=APPEND**

just uncomment this line and replace ASK with APPEND for reuse

Comment: I think it is important to point out that _jmter.properties_ is a file located in the bin folder in the application directory.